# NHibernate.PropertyValueException : not-null property references a null or transient and dependent unit tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nhibernate

I have a strange behaviour when one unit test becomes dependent on another one and fails because of object in NHiberante session.

I'm getting the 'NHibernate.PropertyValueException : not-null property references a null or transient' only if I run all unit tests from fixture (for the simplicity I have only two tests). If I run one of them it always passed.

I feel that I should do some clean-up. I tried session.Clean() and session.Evict(obj), but it didn't help. Could somebody explain what is going on here?

Entity:

```
public class Order
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping (with Loquacious API):

```
public class OrderMapping : ClassMapping<Order>
{
    public OrderMapping()
    {
        Id(e => e.Id, m =>
            {
                m.Generator(Generators.Guid);
                m.Column("OrderId");
            });
        Property(e => e.Name, m => m.NotNullable(true));
    }
}
```

Fixture ctor (the in-memory database are used):

```
var config = new Configuration();
config.CurrentSessionContext<ThreadStaticSessionContext>();
config.DataBaseIntegration(db =>
    {
        db.ConnectionString = "uri=file://:memory:,Version=3";
        db.Dialect<SQLiteDialect>();
        db.Driver<CsharpSqliteDriver>();
        db.ConnectionReleaseMode = ConnectionReleaseMode.OnClose;
        db.KeywordsAutoImport = Hbm2DDLKeyWords.AutoQuote;
        db.LogSqlInConsole = true;
    })
    .SessionFactory()
    .GenerateStatistics();

var mapper = new ModelMapper();
mapper.AddMappings(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetExportedTypes());
config.AddMapping(mapper.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities());

ISessionFactory sessionFactory = config.BuildSessionFactory();
this.session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();

// This will leave the connection open
new SchemaExport(config).Execute(
    true, true, false, this.session.Connection, null);
CurrentSessionContext.Bind(this.session);
```

Unit tests:

```
[Test]
[ExpectedException(typeof(PropertyValueException))]
public void Order_name_is_required()
{
    var order = new Order();
    this.session.Save(order);
}

[Test]
public void Order_was_updated()
{
    var order = new Order { Name = "Name 1" };
    this.session.Save(order);

    this.session.Flush();

    order.Name = "Name 2";
    this.session.Update(order);

    Assert.AreEqual(this.session.Get<Order>(order.Id).Name, "Name 2");
}
```

Order was updated fails with the 'NHibernate.PropertyValueException : not-null property references a null or transient' exception. And actually any other unit test will fail if write after.

**EDIT 1**
Found a solution. Last time when I tried to clean-up the session I used

```
[TestFixtureTearDown]
```

instead of

```
[TearDown]
public void TearDown()
{
    this.session.Clear();
}
```

Which did all clean-up properly before **each** test run and allowed to use the same session and do not re-create the in-memory database structure.
Sorry, I made the obvious mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't reuse the same session for multiple tests.

Also, as per the NHibernate documentation, if an exception has been generated from inside a session/transaction, the session is not guaranteed to be in a consistent state and must be disposed without further use.

Comment: Tried to avoid session creation for each unit test, because in case of in-memory database it means to recreate whole database structure, since the database exists only while connection is open.